# Spring Integration webflux - validate input JSON body

Tags: groovy, spring-integration, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Following is my application configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication, args)
    }


    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow startHeatToJiraFlow() {
        IntegrationFlows
                .from(WebFlux.inboundGateway("/input1")
                .requestMapping { m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST).consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) }
                .requestPayloadType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Mono, ServiceInput))
        )
                .channel("inputtestchannel")
                .get()
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputtestchannel")
    Map replyMessage() {
        return [success: true]
    }


    class ServiceInput {
        @NotBlank
        String input1
        @NotBlank
        String input2
    }
}
```

I expect the following curl request to give me an error since I am not giving an input JSON in the  body.

```
curl  -X POST localhost:8080/input1 -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Instead I am receiving a 200 response

```
{"success":true}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebFlux DSL does not support validation. You can validate the response as part of your processing sequence, as outlined in the [validation section of the webflux docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-handler-validation).

An example of plugging it into Spring Integration can look something like this:

```
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
class ValidatingFlowConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  Validator validator

  @Bean
  Publisher<Message<String>> helloFlow() {
    IntegrationFlows
        .from(
            WebFlux
                .inboundGateway("/greet")
                .requestMapping { m ->
                  m
                      .methods(HttpMethod.POST)
                      .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                }
                .requestPayloadType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Flux, HelloRequest))
                .requestChannel(greetingInputChannel())
        )
        .toReactivePublisher()
  }

  @Bean
  MessageChannel greetingInputChannel() {
    return new FluxMessageChannel()
  }

  @ServiceActivator(
      inputChannel = "greetingInputChannel"
  )
  Flux<String> greetingHandler(Flux<HelloRequest> seq) {
    seq
        .doOnNext { HelloRequest it -> validate(it) }
        .log()
        .map { "Hello, ${it.name}" as String }
  }

  void validate(HelloRequest request) {
    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(request, "request")
    validator.validate(request, errors);
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      throw new ServerWebInputException(errors.toString());
    }
  }
}

@ToString(includeNames = true)
@Validated
class HelloRequest {

  @NotEmpty
  String name
}
```

See [gist](https://gist.github.com/tunaranch/81bd230953a53648219b35d3589f1634) if you want imports.

Comment: I think your `doOnNext()` for validation is not going to be called because the reporter says he doesn't send anything. So, that `Flux<HelloRequest>` is just empty and therefore we go into `complete()` directly without any processing. That how we get that `200 OK` without any errors. I need to know more about such a validation trick in the WebFlux and I'm fully open for improvements in Spring Integration on the matter.

Comment: The trick is described in the webflux manual, (see first link in answer) and it works:

```
❯ http POST http://localhost:8080/greet foo=bar 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors\nField error in object 'request' on field 'name': rejected value [null];...",
    "path": "/greet",
    "status": 400,
    "timestamp": "2019-06-24T23:14:04.150+0000",
    "trace": ".."
}
```

Comment: Here's the full project if you want to have a play: https://github.com/tunaranch/spring-integration-webflux-validation/tree/master

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sample! I will take a look latter. How does it work if you don't send `foo=bar` though?

Comment: See here for out-of-the-box solution in Spring Integration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2977